# How to make the bot if there's a error show it in the chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I've been trying to make a bot, but I've recently been getting alot of errors, but I fix them later though sometime's I test stuff through evaluate and stuff but if there's a error I have to always check back on the editor/console for the error and then go back to fix it so I'm wondering how to do something like this.
[image: Example]

So if you know how to do this please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.py has a [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.on_command_error) event, which takes the error as argument.
You can use it this way:

```py
@bot.event
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Oops!**', description=str(error), color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Here's a list of every [discord exeptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20errors#exceptions).
If you want a custom message for each error, you can do it this way:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_error(ctx, error)
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound):
        msg = "Sorry, this command doesn't exist."
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Oops!**', description=msg, color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```